# google form - drop down and date option

Tags: javascript, google-forms

Hi All  Is there any way in google form to achieve the below  scenarios.

1) I would like to set the restriction in date field (calendar)  for selecting the date. ( I am using date field for selecting  date of birth and i want to restrict the field to select between 18 to 30.)

2) I would like to add an other option for a drop down list that would allow the user to fill in his own choice that isn't on the list.

Kindly someone help.

Comment: Please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, if applicable, [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Each post should include only one question.